# How to get wait screen to show onload when it has CSS styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a good sized web application that is taking 10+ seconds to load and I would like to create a simple "Please wait" text message.

(It's accessing and processing a large amount of information about 30+ employees from 8 different tables, many of which can have over 10K records, and many of these queries are dependent on the results of the previous DME query, so further speeding it up would not be cost effective for a program that will be accessed perhaps 3 times a month and only by internal supervisors.)

I've figured out how to create a div with the basic text that I want and how to hide it when the program is finished and the page is ready to display. What I'm having issues with is the formatting. I would like to center the text, bold it, and increase it's font. However, anytime I try to so much as center it, the message no longer appears. (Tried via CSS and even HMTL). I'm wondering if it is a result of something like the page not wanting to load until all of the styled content is available and formatted. If so, is there a way around this? Even just being able to center would be acceptable.

This works:

```
self.MAIN.document.getElementById("paneBody").innerHTML = '<div id="WaitMsg">Please Wait</div>';
```

This doesn't:

```
self.MAIN.document.getElementById("paneBody").innerHTML = '<div id="WaitMsg" style="text-align:center;">Please Wait</div>';
```

I would appreciate any help or insight on this.

Updated:

Here is the code for this part of the program, which is run onload.

```
function OpenProgram(){
authenticate("frameNm='jsreturn'|funcNm='InitMgrHrsWkd()'|desiredEdit='EM'");

//self.MAIN.document.getElementById("paneBody").innerHTML = '<div id="WaitMsg" >Please Wait</div>';
var waitText = self.MAIN.document.createElement("div");
waitText.innerHTML = "Please Wait";
waitText.style.textAlign = "center";
self.MAIN.document.getElementById("paneBody").appendChild(waitText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a DIV node and then set the settings to it?

```
var waitText = self.MAIN.document.createElement("div");
waitText.innerHTML = "Please Wait";
waitText.style.textAlign = "center";
self.MAIN.document.getElementById("paneBody").appendChild(waitText);
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I implemented it, and followed along in the browser's debugger, which showed that it created the appropriate changes in 'paneBody', however the screen is still blank until the entire page loads. Any other thoughts? FYI, the innerHTML was "<DIV style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">Please Wait</DIV>"

Comment: When do you run your javascript ? Can you post your javscript code or provide it in a JSFiddle ?

Comment: It's run inside of a function that is called 'onload'. function OpenProgram()
{authenticate("frameNm='jsreturn'|funcNm='InitMgrHrsWkd()'|desiredEdit='EM'");      var waitText = self.MAIN.document.createElement("div");
waitText.innerHTML = "Please Wait";
waitText.style.textAlign = "center";
self.MAIN.document.getElementById("paneBody").appendChild(waitText);}

Comment: can you post this as an update of your question in formatted code please, thank you.

Comment: If the onload handler is attached to your DOM then it fires when the page is completly loaded, thats not what you want i guess.

Comment: The code that I posted, commented out in the update, works appropriately, it's message appears as soon as the link to this page is clicked, and disappears when the page is displayed. It's only when styling is applied that it no longer appears.